# SQL Adding row numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a way to add row numbers, but adding duplicated row numbers when one of the columns are duplicates

Logic
* Every time Col1 always start RowNo from 1
* Every time Col1 + Col2 are the same use the same RowNo

Table1

```
Col1    Col2
1       A       
1       B       
1       B       
2       C       
2       D       
2       E       
3       F       
4       G
```

Output should be

```
Col1    Col2  RowNo
1       A       1
1       B       2
1       B       2
2       C       1
2       D       2
2       E       3
3       F       1
4       G       1
```

I have tried,but the output is not correct
select col1,col2
,row_number() over(partition by (col1+col2) order by col1)
from Table1

Answer (score 6):

Use `DENSE_RANK()`:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col2) RowNo
FROM yourTable;
ORDER BY Col1, Col2;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: @Mags Can you mark this answer correct if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number` window function with partitioning on the `col1` column and ordering on `col2`

```
select t.*,
    row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col2) as col3
from your_table t;
```